# Microsoft Word lines

Tags: page-layout, microsoft-word

Could you please give me some advice and various methods to do this work?

Basically I would like to **fill the sheet with lines** like a notebook.
The problem is that when I reach the end of the sheet the lines break up and the program **create a new page to head**.

| Problem 1 (see the img to undersand) | Problem 2 (see the img to undersand) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image: this is the prob guy] |
| When I try to delete the space on the 2nd page the lines are automatically deleted and lose the correct spacing | When I add the line to make the spaces exact then it add another page |

I'm really upset,
How could I solve this mistery?
Thanks for all ideas ✨

Comment: Have you tried changing the layout margins for the page?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't change

Comment: How are you drawing the lines?

Comment: @AndrewH in a very simple way (the only one I know): shamefully: --- and hit enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resolved

**using tabulation** :
Clicking the downward pointing arrow to open the dialog box for the `paragraph` settings.
Then I Clicked the `Tabs...` button at the bottom of the dialog box.

I read online :

> Under `Tab stop position`, type a number that corresponds to the number of inches you want the line to extend from the left margin.

[image: this]

- `Clear All button` pressed on default for prevention
- I've put 18cm on `Tab stop Position` and on `Default Stop` I've set 1.25cm
- Then on `Alignment` I left the left position
- The `Leader` is set on the 4rth selection "_ _ _"
- Starting to press <kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> until the end of page

Then this is the ✨**result** ✨:
[image]

Thanks very much y'all for all the help and clarifications, means very much to me,
owe you

Answer (score 3):

Another way to draw lines in Word

1. Go to Insert -> Table -> Insert Table
2. Set the column to 1 and the rows to ~60, the rows count doesn't matter too much
3. Delete the excess rows from the second page
4. Select all rows in the table, set the border to "No Borders"
5. With the rows selected, set the border to "Inside Borders"

Comment: Well good Idea BUT, the problem 2 remains;
Word create new page...

Comment: resolved in a brutal way,
In the unwanted line of page 2, I changed the **font size**, thus managing to insert the line of the bottom of the page only on page 1